# Spark Streaming Job fails after running few days

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have a 24x7 streaming job , which is running very well for first 44 hrs , after that suddenly all the executor is removed from the cluster and giving the error

```
    java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:465)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:457)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:670)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:192)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.newConnectedPeer(DFSClient.java:3519)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.nextTcpPeer(BlockReaderFactory.java:840)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.getRemoteBlockReaderFromTcp(BlockReaderFactory.java:755)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.build(BlockReaderFactory.java:376)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSInputStream.java:662)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:889)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:942)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:742)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
    at parquet.bytes.BytesUtils.readIntLittleEndian(BytesUtils.java:66)
    at parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:419)
    at parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$2.call(ParquetFileReader.java:238)
    at parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$2.call(ParquetFileReader.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2017-01-18 03:11:15,943] WARN Failed to connect to /hostname:50010 for block, add to deadNodes and continue. java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address (org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient)
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:465)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:457)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:670)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:192)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.newConnectedPeer(DFSClient.java:3519)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.nextTcpPeer(BlockReaderFactory.java:840)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.getRemoteBlockReaderFromTcp(BlockReaderFactory.java:755)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.build(BlockReaderFactory.java:376)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSInputStream.java:662)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:889)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:942)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:742)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
    at parquet.bytes.BytesUtils.readIntLittleEndian(BytesUtils.java:66)
    at parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:419)
    at parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$2.call(ParquetFileReader.java:238)
    at parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$2.call(ParquetFileReader.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

i am doing so many join operations inside the streaming and also i can see that shuffle is increasing every batch not clearing out. Also i am not using any `cache()` operations in it. I tried setting `spark.cleaner.ttl` but no imapact is seen. I have attached the executor section of spark ui.[image]
What will be the reason for this behaviour? what i should do to overcome this ?